# TailwindCSS, Webpack and Sass: class cannot be found while using in CSS file but working fine when inline HTML

Tags: css, webpack, sass, tailwind-css

I have modular CSS (using Sass) and my webpack is throwing errors when I use Tailwind's @apply with some classes. Some of them works, some don't and I can't figure out why. It's working inline in HTML but not in CSS file.

gallery.scss

```
.c-gallery-thumbnails {
  @apply space-x-3;
}
```

base.scss

```
@import "tailwindcss/base";
@import "tailwindcss/components";
@import "tailwindcss/utilities";

import "gallery"
```

webpack

```
module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.[ps]?css$/,
                    use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                        use: [
                            'css-loader',
                            'resolve-url-loader',
                            {
                                loader: 'postcss-loader',
                                options: {
                                    ident: 'postcss',
                                    plugins: [
                                        require('postcss-import'),
                                        require('tailwindcss'),
                                        require('autoprefixer'),
                                    ],
                                },
                            },
                            'sass-loader',
                        ],
                    }),
                },
...
```

And error:

> `@apply` cannot be used with `.space-x-3` because `.space-x-3` either cannot be found, or its actual definition includes a pseudo-selector like :hover, :active, etc. If you're sure that `.space-x-3` exists, make sure that any `@import` statements are being properly processed *before* Tailwind CSS see
> s your CSS, as `@apply` can only be used for classes in the same CSS tree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a read of this: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/using-with-preprocessors/

> For the most cohesive development experience, it's recommended that you use PostCSS exclusively.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to import the .css file where `space-x-3` css rule is defined in `gallery.scss`.